# Making A follow button With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm here to get answers to why my javascript isn't working for the follow button because I add all cdn and scripts but still not working. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $("#follow-button").click(function(){
    if ($("#follow-button").text() == "+ Follow"){
      // *** State Change: To Following ***      
      // We want the button to squish (or shrink) by 10px as a reaction to the click and for it to last 100ms    
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '-=10px' }, 100, 'easeInCubic', function () {});
      
      // then now we want the button to expand out to it's full state
      // The left translation is to keep the button centred with it's longer width
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '+=45px', left: '-=15px' }, 600, 'easeInOutBack', function () { 
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#follow-button").text("Following");

        // Animate the background transition from white to green. Using JQuery Color
        $("#follow-button").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#2EB82E",
          borderColor: "#2EB82E"
        }, 1000 );
      });
    }else{
      
      // *** State Change: Unfollow ***     
      // Change the button back to it's original state
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '-=25px', left: '+=15px' }, 600, 'easeInOutBack', function () { 
        $("#follow-button").text("+ Follow");
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#3399FF");
        $("#follow-button").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        $("#follow-button").css("border-color", "#3399FF");
      });
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
#follow-button {
  color: #3399FF;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px; 
  cursor: hand;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="follow-button"> Follow</button>
```

Is there a solution to fix this type of error? I tried google but no answers. I thought you guys could help.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Whats the problem??

Comment: The follow button doesn't want to go from follow to following

Comment: You're querying the DOM more than needed. Cache `$("#follow-button")`, i.e. `var $follow = $("#follow-button"); $follow.css();`. You can also chain methods, i.e. `$follow.css().text()`. For `css()`, pass an object instead of multiple calls to `css()`, i.e. `css( { color: 'white', border: 'none' } )`. Like you did with `animate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues in your codes:

1. `easeInOutBack` is not defined, so uses built-in easing function=`linear` or `swing` instead
2. `$("#follow-button").css("color", "#fff");` will cause text and background are same color, so uses `#2EB82E` instead.

You can check the details for [JQuery animate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp).

After fix them, the codes will be like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $("#follow-button").click(function(){
    if ($("#follow-button").text() == "+ Follow"){
      // *** State Change: To Following ***      
      // We want the button to squish (or shrink) by 10px as a reaction to the click and for it to last 100ms    
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '-=10px' }, 100, 'linear', function () {});
      
      // then now we want the button to expand out to it's full state
      // The left translation is to keep the button centred with it's longer width
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '+=45px', left: '-=15px' }, 600, 'linear', function () { 
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#2EB82E");
        $("#follow-button").text("Following");

        // Animate the background transition from white to green. Using JQuery Color
        $("#follow-button").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#2EB82E",
          borderColor: "#2EB82E"
        }, 1000 );
      });
    }else{
      
      // *** State Change: Unfollow ***     
      // Change the button back to it's original state
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '-=25px', left: '+=15px' }, 600, 'linear', function () { 
        $("#follow-button").text("+ Follow");
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#3399FF");
        $("#follow-button").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        $("#follow-button").css("border-color", "#3399FF");
      });
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
#follow-button {
  color: #3399FF;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px; 
  cursor: hand;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="follow-button"> Follow</button>
```

Comment: In the animate docs I've seen the '-=15px' syntax,  like `$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",`

There's something else over there . . .

Comment: @FelipeQuirós, you are correct, just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery's `html()` function, as `text()` doesn't do what you think it should do - http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
$("#follow-button").html("Following");
```

Answer (score 0):

> `if ($("#follow-button").text() == "+ Follow")`

You're comparing the button text with "+ Follow" yet your button text is just "Follow" so your `if` block will never run.

Also see Adam's answer for the correct way to get/set the contents of your button.

Answer (score 0):

The `easings` you are using are not defined, and that is why you are getting the error.

Please check [jQuery Easings Main Page](https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) for more info.

I have fixed your error, but I guess your code still needs some improvements style and coloring wise.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    

  $("#follow-button").click(function(){
    if ($("#follow-button").text() == "+ Follow"){
      // *** State Change: To Following ***      
      // We want the button to squish (or shrink) by 10px as a reaction to the click and for it to last 100ms    
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '-=10px' }, 100, 'linear', function () {});
      
      // then now we want the button to expand out to it's full state
      // The left translation is to keep the button centred with it's longer width
      $("#follow-button").animate({ width: '+=45px', left: '-=15px' }, 600, 'linear', function () { 
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#follow-button").text("Following");

        // Animate the background transition from white to green. Using JQuery Color
        $("#follow-button").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#2EB82E",
          borderColor: "#2EB82E"
        }, 1000 );
      });
    }
    else{
      // *** State Change: Unfollow ***     
      // Change the button back to it's original state
      $("#follow-button").animate({
          width: '-=25px',
          left: '+=15px'
        }, 600, 'linear', function () {
        $("#follow-button").text("+ Follow");
        $("#follow-button").css("color", "#3399FF");
        $("#follow-button").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
        $("#follow-button").css("border-color", "#3399FF");
      });
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
#follow-button {
  color: #3399FF;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px; 
  cursor: hand;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="follow-button"> Follow</button>
```